# Mac OS: Execute a command in .zshrc (or .bashrc) only for new windows but not for new tabs

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

I'm trying to change the "default working directory" for Terminal.app and it seems that is not possible (from my research so far). I could achieve this using ~/.zshrc (by adding "cd ~/Desktop") but unfortunately that changes the behavior of all new Tabs.

I'm hoping to have new Tabs open in my current working directory. How can I make sure that only new windows (ideally, only the first window) open with a chosen directory?

Comment: What defines the "current working directory" for you (the one you want to reuse if you upon a new tab)? Also, it's not clear whether you want to have this solved, or the problem of opening the first tab of a new window in a pre-defined directory.

Comment: @nohillside "current working directory" is the directory I'm currently in while opening a new Tab. Sorry, I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: But aren‘t you asking two things here: a) how to run a command only for the first tab in a window and b) how to use the current directory as the directory for a new tab?

Comment: @nohillside Oh, I see your point now.. Fortunately, (b) can be implemented with the Settings of the Terminal: "New tabs open with: Same Working Directory".

Comment: One limitation of Terminal.app is that you can not specify a different behaviour, depending on wheter it starts up a new shell in a new window or in a new tab. However for iTerm2, there is a configuration option, where you can set a different Home directory for new windows and new tabs. Note that even in this case, you better configure your shell to start as a non-login shell, because a login shell will likely put you back into your home directory. But even in iTerm2, you can't query from inside your shell, whether you are in a tab or in a new window.

Comment: Perhaps a cleaner approach would be to create various profiles. You can configure each profile so that it does something differently. Whether opening a new window or a new tab, you would then have to manually choose the profile you want to have.

Comment: Something like `case $(pwd) in $HOME) cd ~/Desktop;; esac` would work to switch to Desktop only if the current directory is the home directory. This doesn't care whether you are in a new tab or not, but would approximate the case where you open new tabs in whatever other directory is current in the tab you're on (provided it's not the home directory, of course).

Comment: @triplee Thanks, this works nicely for me since I hardly do anything from within $HOME directory